# Store common info in a file in android

Tags: android, sharing, file-sharing, android-sharing, data-sharing

Can I create and use a file in android which can be accessed and written into by another android app, not signed by the same signature on the play store?

Comment: Please read this documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: The answer is yes.